# Creating a simple GET request from crunchbase api

Tags: javascript, api, curl, get

I recently got access to the crunchbase api and have been having issues getting data from it in javascript. I have tested curl -v  -X GET "https://api.crunchbase.com/v/2/organizations?query=facebook&user_key=MYKEY&page=1" and receive data correctly from crunchbase in my terminal.

How can I properly convert this curl request to a JSON request in javascript? I have tried this in many ways and keep getting the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401."

There must be a simple way to do this and I think I am simply just missing it.

Thank you!